# How to enforce 100%/vh on html when a dev tool is open at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwxOy.png)I have my HTML, body and root tags set to 100vh. But when I'm opening my site with a dev tool open (true for Chrom an FF), part of the page or the whole page depends on what page we are on shrinks by the dev tool size.

I have tried setting all kinds of different height sizes. If I set min-height or height in pixels then it solves this problem but I do not wish to have my height in pixels.

```
html{
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#root{
  height: 100vh;
}
.coming-soon{
    background-color: #24273a;
    background-image: url('../svg-png-ext/shapes.svg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.advantage-header{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 65px;
}

.middle-container-soon{

    background-image: url("../svg-png-ext/Oval.svg");
    position: absolute;
    top: 21%;
    left: 37%;
}

.soon-title{

    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Metric;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    list-style-type: none;

}
.back-buttons-container{

    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.coming-soon-buttons{

    height: 40px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #5DB2C9;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
}
.social-links-container{

    width: 73px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 24%;
}
.prevent-pointer{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.linkedin-icon{
    fill:white;
}
.soon-advantage-icon{
    height: 36.81px;
    width: 25.63px;
}
.more-size{
    font-size: 44px;
}
.soon-position{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.coming-soon-btn-container{
    display: grid;
    margin-left: 90px;
}
.social-icon{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px;
}
.image-size{
    height: 100px;
}
```

I expect that when the dev tool is open at the bottom and I scroll down I will see the background image and the rest of my CSS but all I get is a white page with buttons.

Comment: If the dev tools are taking up space at the bottom of the window, then the viewport height *has* to be shorter, there isn't as much space for it! If that's a problem, undock the dev tools from the window.

Comment: I am aware of this possibility thank's, but I am looking for a solution and to understand the reason, not a workaround.

Comment: The reason is that the dev tools are not part of the viewport. The viewport is where the page is displayed.

Comment: If your problem is you want more space with devtools open, dock it to the side.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Developer Tools are not part of the `viewport` object as far as CSS is concerned. You can use JS to size the page instead, but what you want cannot be accomplished by CSS alone. CSS `vw` & `vh` are calculated the same way as `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

The address bar, window border, viewport, and Dev Tools are all included in `window.outerHeight`. You can find the height of these elements to detect if Dev Tools is open by subtracting `window.innerHeight` from `window.outerHeight`. If the difference is greater than the height of the address bar & bookmark bar (address bar is 70px, 102px if bookmark bar is open *in Chrome*, I don't have the values on hand for FF)

```
function adjustViewHeight() {
    document.getElementById('root').style.height = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight - 70
}

window.onresize = adjustViewHeight

adjustViewHeight()
```

EDIT: This is not intended to be used in a production application or website.